# Is there an English translation of Der Langrisser?

Tags: snes

I've always liked the Langrisser series.  I've seen videos and screenshots for an English version of Der Langrisser (SNES) but as far as I can see, only a Japanese version was released.  Did they ever release an English cart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there has never been an English release of Langrisser, the snes version with screen shots you see are from a fan made translation patch for the game.